# Add continuous controls to UserForm

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

Once again I seem stuck with vba word 2011 on Mac.
What I want to do is to add continuous TextBoxes to my UserForm. It is for a document to write invoices. The following is the code that I figured out:

```
Private Sub cbRechnungPosHinzu_Click()
    Dim Cntrl As control
    Dim PosName As String
    Dim BetName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2
    If UFRechnung.Controls.Count = (20 + (i * 2)) Then
        i = i + 1
    Else
        With UFRechnung
            .Height = UFRechnung.Height + 45
            .cbRechnungPosHinzu.Top = .cbRechnungPosHinzu.Top + 45
            .cbRechnungPosWeg.Top = .cbRechnungPosWeg.Top + 45
            .cbRechnungCancel.Top = .cbRechnungCancel.Top + 45
            .cbRechnungOk.Top = .cbRechnungOk.Top + 45
            PosName = "txtPos" & i
            BetName = "txtBet" & i
            Set Cntrl = UFRechnung.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", PosName, True)
            With Cntrl
'                .Name = PosName #already defined by Set Cntrl
'                .Visible = True
'                .Enabled = True
                .Top = UFRechnung.Controls("txtPos" & (i - 1)).Top + 45
                .Left = 20
                .Width = 470
                .Height = 25
                .AutoSize = False
'                .Font = "Calibri Light, 14" #These specials do not work on Mac
'                .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken
'                .TextAlign = fmTextAlignLeft
'                .WordWrap = True
            End With
            Set Cntrl = UFRechnung.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", BetName, True)
            With Cntrl
'                .Name = BetName
'                .Visible = True
'                .Enabled = True
                .Top = UFRechnung.Controls("txtBet" & (i - 1)).Top + 45
                .Left = 510
                .Width = 470
                .Height = 25
                .AutoSize = False
'                .Font = "Calibri Light, 14"
'                .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken
'                .TextAlign = fmTextAlignLeft
'                .WordWrap = True
            End With
            Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=("Betrag" & (i - 1))
            Selection.MoveRight
            Selection.TypeText Text:=vbNewLine
            Selection.FormFields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormTextInput) _
                .Name = ("Position" & i)
            Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
            Selection.TypeText ("CHF")
            Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
            Selection.FormFields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormTextInput) _
                 .Name = ("Betrag" & i)
         End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Now well my problem is, that it only adds the two TextBoxes the first time I click the button, after that only the part

```
With UFRechnung
    .Height = UFRechnung.Height + 45
    .cbRechnungPosHinzu.Top = .cbRechnungPosHinzu.Top + 45
    .cbRechnungPosWeg.Top = .cbRechnungPosWeg.Top + 45
    .cbRechnungCancel.Top = .cbRechnungCancel.Top + 45
    .cbRechnungOk.Top = .cbRechnungOk.Top + 45
```

seems to work. What am I doing wrong? Any ideas for an easier code?

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=("Betrag" & (i - 1))
Selection.MoveRight
Selection.TypeText Text:=vbNewLine
Selection.FormFields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormTextInput) _
    .Name = ("Position" & i)
Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
Selection.TypeText ("CHF")
Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
Selection.FormFields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormTextInput) _
    .Name = ("Betrag" & i)
```

This part also works perfectly.

Thanks in advance. CU Kath

********************************************* Information added *********************************************

By the way:

```
If UFRechnung.Controls.Count = (20 + (i * 2)) Then
    i = i + 1
```

was my way to check how many Controls are active in my UserForm as I couldn't check if the TextBoxes with a specific name are already existing. As it always adds 2 Textboxes the next time it checks it has increased by 2 checkboxes so for i = 1 I have 22 (20 + 2) controls, for i=2 I have 24 (20 + 4) controls in my UserForm. Hope I made this clearer for you to understand.

(I even found 2-3 mistakes, but still no luck...)

```
UFSomething = UserForm
cbSomething = ControlButton
txtSomething = TextBox Name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again found the answer myself... :)

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub cbRechnungPosHinzu_Click()
    Dim Cntrl As control
    Dim PosName As String
    Dim BetName As String
    Dim k As Integer
    k = (((UFRechnung.Controls.Count - 20) / 2) + 1)
    With UFRechnung
        .Height = UFRechnung.Height + 45
        .cbRechnungPosHinzu.Top = .cbRechnungPosHinzu.Top + 45
        .cbRechnungPosWeg.Top = .cbRechnungPosWeg.Top + 45
        .cbRechnungCancel.Top = .cbRechnungCancel.Top + 45
        .cbRechnungOk.Top = .cbRechnungOk.Top + 45
        PosName = "txtPos" & k
        BetName = "txtBet" & k
        Set Cntrl = UFRechnung.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", PosName, True)
        With Cntrl
            .Top = UFRechnung.Controls("txtPos" & (k - 1)).Top + 45
            .Left = 20
            .Width = 470
            .Height = 25
            .AutoSize = False
        End With
        Set Cntrl = UFRechnung.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", BetName, True)
        With Cntrl
            .Top = UFRechnung.Controls("txtBet" & (k - 1)).Top + 45
            .Left = 510
            .Width = 470
            .Height = 25
            .AutoSize = False
        End With
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=("Betrag" & (k - 1))
        Selection.MoveRight
        Selection.TypeText Text:=vbNewLine
        Selection.FormFields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormTextInput) _
            .Name = ("Position" & k)
        Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
        Selection.TypeText ("CHF")
        Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
        Selection.FormFields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormTextInput) _
           .Name = ("Betrag" & k)
        Exit Sub
    End With
End Sub
```

With the line

```
k = (((UFRechnung.Controls.Count - 20) / 2) + 1)
```

I did the trick... I count the amount of controls as the Userform appears by default. Easier than count is

```
debug.print Userform.controls.count
```

Mine are 22 normally but I already have txtpos1 and txtbet1 by default in the userform so I have to subtract them for the amount of the Controls as I want to add Textboxes such as txtpos2 and txtbet2 (continuously numbered). So when I have 22 Controls I have one txtpos and one txtbet, when I have 24 controls txtpos2 and txtbet2 are already in the userform... It's actually not so complicated once you see the whole thing. Maybe this might help someone else someday :) (when I was searching for solutions I didn't find anything....)

The work here is done, but thx for the help.

CU Kath

Answer (score 1):

I may be confused by the non-english code, but it looks like the variable i is a local variable in the button click handler. It will be reset to 2 each time the button is clicked. Instead, declare it the UserForm (Declarations) scope and initialize it in the UserForm_Initialize() handler.

Comment: Yeah, well sorry for that.... This is the code that is being run if you click a button in the userform. I have to admit I don't know how to declare it in the scope.... (Acutally I have only been learning VBA for about 3 months...) What is really confusing for me, is that the part with the selections works perfectly, even with the i.... maybe i just got an idea thanks to you.... leeet's see...

Comment: I was mistaken... I believe my problem is, that I can't check which textboxes already exist in my userform by the code if there are Textboxes added continuously.... I really got the impression I'm missing something.
Btw I'm really sorry for my bad english today ^^

Comment: Please clarify  'added continuously'. If the code in your original question is the only code adding textboxes, why can't you keep track of how many were added?

Comment: In my userform I have a button. When that button is pressed there should be added 2 textboxes. Each time the button is pressed. These Textboxes need to be named so that I can add the content to the document. But it is hard to check if a textbox already exists with this name in the userform. Does this help?

Comment: If I could just upload my userform... maybe this would help... This userform will be used to add all information concerning the invoice, so title of the invoice, invoicenumber, aso. This code here is used to add more values with it's description to the invoice, so there is always a short description ("Position" in the Userform) and the value ("Betrag") that is being added. "Rechnung" btw means invoice. :)

Comment: I have been testing some more and the problem is that the following part of code doesn't work:  i = i+1. Why though? Why does i stay 2?

Comment: Chaz: do you know how to check if a Textbox already exists? The code UFRechnung.Textbox.Exists("Betrag" & i) doesn't work...